# How may I synchronize two mariadb databases from a date on?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, relational-database, mariadb

I am trying to replicate my production database, and in the process clean some tables. In the new one, I got rid of old entries (moved to a "historical" db). This implied a lot of time and concatenation of deletes. Now that I have it as I wanted to, I need to synchronize the newest entries in the production database (which is running and cannot be stopped), but I don't want the old entries to come back. The intention is to switch between the two databases at some point.

I thought of using Navicat's Data Synchronization tool, but it wouldn't allow me to filter the entries based on dates (or any filter at all, for what it's worth). Can anyone suggest a method/tool to use for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a script you can run or schedule if you have a good datetime and/or PK int everywhere? Parents first, FK-dependent children second

Comment: Single machine?  Or Master-Slave?

Comment: Hi @Drew. Not all tables have dates or PKs. Some of them do. I added PKs to every table in the new DB.

Comment: @Rick, different machines, not currently configured as Master-Slave, but a DB migration, I would say. The new DB would substitute the old one at some point.

Comment: do you know how to do it for tables that have a PK that auto increments

Comment: Synchronizing a live table, without already established Master-Slave, with or without a PK, and without any downtime, is a challenge.

Comment: We like challenges :)

Comment: Hi everybody. For what all of you are saying, I see that I may have to just fill the new DB with all data from the old one, and re-drop the old entries. Thanks anyhow!